# Entity Framework Core 5 turn off loading NavigationProperties

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading

How can I turn off loading navigation properties in EF Core 5 when I get data from the `DBContext`?

I tried to add:

```
public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options)
        : base(options)
{
   this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

but navigation properties are still loaded.

[Loaded NavProp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdhio.png)

**Edit**: I added to `AddDBContext` option

```
UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
```

and it looks like this works.

Hope it doesn't spoil anything else?

**Edit-2** `UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);` - ok its not what I need....

I getting data like:

`List<Data> dataList = await _dataContext.Data.Where(w => idMeters.Contains(w.IdMeter.Value)).ToListAsync();`

In result I have Data object with IdMeterNavigation, and IdMeterNavigation have another NavigationProperties...
I don't want to load any NavigationProperties how I can do that?

I even removed `virtual` from class fields and they are still loaded.

Comment: Are you using AutoMapper (or any object mapper), or doing any serialization/deserialization?

Comment: I getting data using: ` await _dataContext.Data.Where(w => ... ).ToListAsync();`
But I added to `AddDBContext` options: `UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);` and looks like works

Comment: I don't think you'd want that. Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking)

Comment: @blane post the actual code *as text*. What you want is the *default behavior*. You actually have to do extra work to load related entities, either by using `Include`, using lazy loading, or actually including the navigation property in the ouotput.

Comment: `Hope it doesn't spoil anything else?` yes it does. It's no longer possible to track and persist changes to entities. That's not what this setting is about. [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/) explains how related entities are loaded. `LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` has the *opposite* effect from what you assumed. Lazy loading means loading relations only when needed. Which is what you wanted

Comment: I have set `this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` but NavProp still is loading why? I never want to load a NavigationProperties

Comment: EF *always* executes relationship fixup. You must have loaded the entities separately into the context. Forget all these lazy loading and tracking settings.

Comment: Any chance `IdMeterNavigation`  being a reference to [owned entity type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)? Because these are the only ones which eager load automatically.

Comment: In DBContext in OnModelCreating: `entity.HasOne(d => d.IdMeterNavigation)                    .WithMany(p => p.Data).HasForeignKey(d => d.IdMeter)                    .HasConstraintName("FK_DATA_METER");`

Answer (score 2):

Default behaviour of EF is to not load related entities.
In order to load related entities you could use:

- eager loading
- explicit loading
- **select loading**
- **lazy loading**

So, for me it seems that you have **ENABLED** lazy loading or you actually do a **SELECT** loading using "Select" LINQ extension or kind of automapper software.

Check if you havent enabled lazy loading for sure...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy

Comment: I add DBContext like this:
`services.AddDbContext<DataContextCORE>(x => { x .UseSqlServer($"", sqlServerOptions => SqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(serverConfiguration.CORE.CommandTimeoutInSec))
                    .UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory);
            });`

In DataContext Ctor I have `this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`

DBContext was generated with scaffold. I'm getting data using `_dataContextDW.Data.Where(w =>...)`
Exist other way to disable lazy, select loading?